# QuadTree or KD Tree for objective c?

Tags: objective-c, c, kdtree, quadtree

I'm looking a while for a decent piece of code to use in my app, in one of those algorithms.
I found this example: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/K-d_tree#C
But when I put the code in xcode, I get an errors, for example:

"use of undeclared identifier", "expected ';' at the end of declaration".
I guess a header file is missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I copied the code from the link and made a minor edit which moved
"swap" from being an inline nested function to a static function.
Compiled with "gcc -C99 file.c" and it compiled ok. So, no, it doesn't
need some include file. Maybe you mis pasted it.

If you are happy with this answer, you could accept it. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_DIM 3
struct kd_node_t{
    double x[MAX_DIM];
    struct kd_node_t *left, *right;
};

inline double
dist(struct kd_node_t *a, struct kd_node_t *b, int dim)
{
    double t, d = 0;
    while (dim--) {
        t = a->x[dim] - b->x[dim];
        d += t * t;
    }
    return d;
}

    static void swap(struct kd_node_t *x, struct kd_node_t *y) {
        double tmp[MAX_DIM];
        memcpy(tmp,  x->x, sizeof(tmp));
        memcpy(x->x, y->x, sizeof(tmp));
        memcpy(y->x, tmp,  sizeof(tmp));
    }

/* see quickselect method */
struct kd_node_t*
find_median(struct kd_node_t *start, struct kd_node_t *end, int idx)
{
    if (end <= start) return NULL;
    if (end == start + 1)
        return start;


    struct kd_node_t *p, *store, *md = start + (end - start) / 2;
    double pivot;
    while (1) {
        pivot = md->x[idx];

        swap(md, end - 1);
        for (store = p = start; p < end; p++) {
            if (p->x[idx] < pivot) {
                if (p != store)
                    swap(p, store);
                store++;
            }
        }
        swap(store, end - 1);

        /* median has duplicate values */
        if (store->x[idx] == md->x[idx])
            return md;

        if (store > md) end = store;
        else        start = store;
    }
}

struct kd_node_t*
make_tree(struct kd_node_t *t, int len, int i, int dim)
{
    struct kd_node_t *n;

    if (!len) return 0;

    if ((n = find_median(t, t + len, i))) {
        i = (i + 1) % dim;
        n->left  = make_tree(t, n - t, i, dim);
        n->right = make_tree(n + 1, t + len - (n + 1), i, dim);
    }
    return n;
}

/* global variable, so sue me */
int visited;

void nearest(struct kd_node_t *root, struct kd_node_t *nd, int i, int dim,
        struct kd_node_t **best, double *best_dist)
{
    double d, dx, dx2;

    if (!root) return;
    d = dist(root, nd, dim);
    dx = root->x[i] - nd->x[i];
    dx2 = dx * dx;

    visited ++;

    if (!*best || d < *best_dist) {
        *best_dist = d;
        *best = root;
    }

    /* if chance of exact match is high */
    if (!*best_dist) return;

    if (++i >= dim) i = 0;

    nearest(dx > 0 ? root->left : root->right, nd, i, dim, best, best_dist);
    if (dx2 >= *best_dist) return;
    nearest(dx > 0 ? root->right : root->left, nd, i, dim, best, best_dist);
}

#define N 1000000
#define rand1() (rand() / (double)RAND_MAX)
#define rand_pt(v) { v.x[0] = rand1(); v.x[1] = rand1(); v.x[2] = rand1(); }
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    struct kd_node_t wp[] = {
        {{2, 3}}, {{5, 4}}, {{9, 6}}, {{4, 7}}, {{8, 1}}, {{7, 2}}
    };
    struct kd_node_t this = {{9, 2}};
    struct kd_node_t *root, *found, *million;
    double best_dist;

    root = make_tree(wp, sizeof(wp) / sizeof(wp[1]), 0, 2);

    visited = 0;
    found = 0;
    nearest(root, &this, 0, 2, &found, &best_dist);

    printf(">> WP tree\nsearching for (%g, %g)\n"
        "found (%g, %g) dist %g\nseen %d nodes\n\n",
        this.x[0], this.x[1],
        found->x[0], found->x[1], sqrt(best_dist), visited);

    million = calloc(N, sizeof(struct kd_node_t));
    srand(time(0));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) rand_pt(million[i]);

    root = make_tree(million, N, 0, 3);
    rand_pt(this);

    visited = 0;
    found = 0;
    nearest(root, &this, 0, 3, &found, &best_dist);

    printf(">> Million tree\nsearching for (%g, %g, %g)\n"
        "found (%g, %g, %g) dist %g\nseen %d nodes\n",
        this.x[0], this.x[1], this.x[2],
        found->x[0], found->x[1], found->x[2],
        sqrt(best_dist), visited);

    /* search many random points in million tree to see average behavior.
       tree size vs avg nodes visited:
        10      ~  7
        100     ~ 16.5
        1000        ~ 25.5
        10000       ~ 32.8
        100000      ~ 38.3
        1000000     ~ 42.6
        10000000    ~ 46.7              */
    int sum = 0, test_runs = 100000;
    for (i = 0; i < test_runs; i++) {
        found = 0;
        visited = 0;
        rand_pt(this);
        nearest(root, &this, 0, 3, &found, &best_dist);
        sum += visited;
    }
    printf("\n>> Million tree\n"
        "visited %d nodes for %d random findings (%f per lookup)\n",
        sum, test_runs, sum/(double)test_runs);

    // free(million);

    return 0;
}
```